# Flutter: How can I create repeating push notifications?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification

how can I create repeating push notifications? I want to be able to schedule those at least a little bit flexible (e. g. every year, every 3 months, every month, ... nothing too fancy).

I already tried the package flutter_local_notifications but for me it looks like I just can create repeating notifications for every week or every day.

I am already using firebase so I would be open to any solutions which are based on that.

My goal is the following: The users of my app should be able to create a (repeating) reminder in form of a push notification.

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase-based solution: Assuming you are on the Blaze plan, you could create a scheduled cloud function using PubSub, like [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions). Such methods are billed based on the number of total **functions**, not invocations, so you have some flexibility, though if you need this to be a per-user feature, it might not be a viable solution. If you can provide a minimal granularity (for example, 5 minutes), you could deploy a single scheduled function to notify all pending "tasks" to users, while the users can schedule a reminder by saving an entity in Cloud Firestore, which describes the exact time and date when they would receive a reminder. The scheduled function then maps all currently pending tasks, and deleted handled tasks.

For example, in TypeScript you might do something like:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

const serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")

// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
})

// Declare the exported PubSub function
export const checkPendingNotifications = = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!')
  const db = admin.firestore()

  const scheduledTasks = await db.collection('s').get();
  scheduledTasks.forEach(taskSnapshot => {
    const data = taskSnapshot.data()
    // ... TODO Check for user-submitted dates in data
  })

  return null;
});
```

Comment: Sounds great. Can you provide me with some code? I find it very hard to find example-code.

Comment: Yes, I've added a basic example to the answer

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, consider marking it and upvoting it for future reference.

Comment: @MikiMints I added your code in index.js file and converting it to javascript, but what should I add in my classes to receive these notifications? I really working hard for more than a month to apply notification to my graduation app but it still doesn't work, I really need help, please